# How to show user's own retweet of other people's tweet in discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, discord, discord.js

Im trying to add a retweet feature to my discord bot such that it can show the user retweeted post. I have tried to do something like this, but when i run my code it still only post new tweets. Can anyone help troubleshoot?

Let me try to simplify the scenario cuze i think it might be abit hard to say what i actually wanna achieve.

- Imagine if i am a twitter user called @hojitea(jus an example). I follow a user in twitter called @readDonaldTrump.
- What i would want my discord bot to do is to not only get new tweet that @realDonaldTrump has posted, but also the retweets that he did.
- So like this image(i wanna get this retweet in my discord bot):[image]
- Note that in the image, it states 'Donald J. Trump Retweeted', which is what i want my discord bot to also display, not any other user. This is unachievable based on my current code.

Right now, this is how it looks like(a snippet of the entire source code):

```js
// setting up necessary libraries
require('dotenv').config();
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const botCommands = require('./commands');
const Twitter = require('twit')

//Set up discord and twitter token blah blah blah...

const twitterClient = new Twitter(twitterConf);

// create a stream to follow tweets
const stream = twitterClient.stream('statuses/filter', {
    follow: '25073877', //donaldtrump twt id
});

const dest = '765217504305872896' //streaming twts to #twitter channel

// TWITTER MAIN PROCESS
// stream directly to that channel
stream.on('tweet', tweet => {
    if (tweet.retweeted_status  //to prevent other user tweets and only get specifically from the user
        || tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str 
        || tweet.in_reply_to_user_id
        || tweet.in_reply_to_user_id_str
        || tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name) return true;
      
    if (tweet.current_user_retweet) { //to show the retweeted message by the user
        const twitterRetweetMessage = `**${tweet.user.name} (@${tweet.user.screen_name}) new retweet!**\n https://twitter.com/${tweet.user.screen_name}/status/${tweet.id_str}`
        bot.channels.cache.get(dest).send(twitterRetweetMessage);
        console.log(`A new retweet has been posted by @${tweet.user.screen_name}!`)
        return false;
    }
    const twitterMessage = `**${tweet.user.name} (@${tweet.user.screen_name}) new tweet!**\n https://twitter.com/${tweet.user.screen_name}/status/${tweet.id_str}`
    bot.channels.cache.get(dest).send(twitterMessage);
    console.log(`A new tweet has been posted by @${tweet.user.screen_name}!`)
    return false;
});

// acknowledge bot has connected
bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}!`);
});
```

*DISCLAIMER: I AM NOT A US CITIZEN BY ANY CHANCE. THE USERNAME USED IS PURELY MEANT AS AN EXAMPLE AND NOT A US ELECTION PROPOGANDA.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/get-statuses-show-id) (this link is for `GET statuses/show/:id`, but all Tweet objects follow the same format anyway), `current_user_retweet` is only supplied if the authenticating user (`@hojitea`) retweeted the tweet. Since the Tweet object is supplied directly after a Tweet is posted, it is near impossible that the authenticating user has already retweeted the tweet.

You have to remove `tweet.retweeted_status` from the big `if` statement if you want to parse retweets. This will also show all Retweets of that person's tweets, so to filter out tweets by other users, just check if the ID of the user you're subscribed to is equal to the id of the user in the tweet object (`tweet.user.id`). You'd want to put this before processing any tweets, so you'd put it right before the aforementioned `if` statement.

To check if the Tweet is a Retweet, use `tweet.retweeted_status` for your if statement instead. This value is always supplied for retweets, but is always null for non-retweets.

```js
// ...
if (tweet.retweeted_status) { // true if the tweet was a retweet.
    const twitterRetweetMessage = `**${tweet.user.name} ...`
// ...
```

P.S.: If I were to be a bit nitpicky, the message should be `` `A new Tweet has been retweeted by @${tweet.user.screen_name}!` `` instead, since the retweeting user technically didn't post the Tweet.

Comment: So will it look something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/1ac6zr74/)? Would you mind if u help me check?